# Can I get all my users emails from CloudKit DB?

Tags: cloudkit

I am evaluating my BaaS options and picking between CloudKit and Firebase to store users and their content.

Typically users will register in my app via "Sign in with Apple", "...with Google", "...with email", etc. And after a while, I would like to get a list of of all my users' emails and send them an email newsletter.

Now the problem I'm facing with CloudKit is that after the user "Signs in with Apple" their info seems to be written to their private DB, which I don't have access to. Should I copy everything to the public DB? Is this allowed by Apple?